# Lightning flow builder

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

I had to debug an existing flow and ended up looking at this crayonish flow which took my brain a few minutes to remap the existing setup. Purely Aesthetic point of view/OCD point of view too.

1) IS there a way to make the lines straight in flow builder, bugs to see the squiggly lines flowing all over( like holding shift or some crazy shortcut that can make the lines straight)?

2) How to make a loop look like a loop and not more a square :(?

I do not want to switch back to the flash based flow and want to stick to this version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to change the rendering of the connectors. (I'm the Flow Builder PM - we've had several bits of feedback on how the connectors are drawn and snap-to-grid, and we're looking at options. It's probably closer to a Winter '20 fix, based on current assessments of other functionality we're trying to finish for Summer '19, and where we are in the release cycle. Please make purchases based on existing functionality and not this forward looking statement.)